# OAuth Refresh Token does not deserialize / invalid_grant

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin

I have followed the wonderful tutorial by Taiser Joudah for implementing refresh tokens with Asp.Net Web Api 2 and Owin. It all went so well...except I can't get it to work. :-) It all "seems" like it works up until the point I request a refresh token. Then all I get back is:

```
“error”: “invalid_grant”
```

and no description to go with. One of the comments on that post had the same symptom and the response was to generate a MachineKey for the web.config. I tried this but it didn't help. And I'm thinking that maybe only applies when the Auth and Resource server are not the same anyway, which in this case they are.

The bottom line is using PostMan I can make the request for the refresh token and in ReceiveAsync the context.Ticket deserialization does not work. After the call to “context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);” the context.Ticket is still null. Curiously if I manually deserialize the ProtectedTicket using the Acccess Token’s AccessTokenFormat it will deserialize properly. But it does not work using the Refresh Token's RefreshTokenFormat object:

```
var thisWorks = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
var thisDoesnt = Startup.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenFormat.Unprotect(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
```

It sure seems like a config problem…but I’ve racked my brains and compared a lot of samples. What could be causing this?

EDIT
Oops...meant to link to the tutorial article: http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

Comment: :-| Abort mission. Self-inflicted wounds. It's a long story but essentially it was doing exactly what I told it to do, I just didn't realize I told it to do that... Essentially I was manually generating the initial refresh token but serializing it with the AccessTokenFormat instead of the RefreshTokenFormat.

Comment: I was having this exact same issue but I wasn't setting the ExpiresUtc correctly

Comment: “error”: “invalid_grant” may also mean that refresh token is expired. I have discovered that I was issuing a lifespan of 0 seconds to my refresh tokens

Comment: @DennisWelu I followed the exact same tutorial, how did you fix this issue?

Comment: @Motoko My issue is basically what I wrote - where I was supposed to use RefreshTokenFormat I had copied in AccessTokenFormat. From here and elsewhere its clear there can be many causes for this error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the order you create the `refresh_token`  with `CreateAsync`. 
Make sure you follow order bellow:

```
context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = refreshTokenProperties.IssuedUtc;
context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = refreshTokenProperties.ExpiresUtc;
context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
```

Then you can persist the token into DB. But have in mind that it is not necessary to persist. You can `DeserializeTicket` from `context.Token` in `ReceiveAsync`:

```
public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
{
    context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
    if (context.Ticket != null)
    {            
        context.SetTicket(context.Ticket);            
    }            
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Following the same tutorial, I had the same problem, this worked for me

```
public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
{
    //...
    context.Ticket.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;

    token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();
    //...
}
```