# ASP.NET API OAuth2 Refresh token - Deserialize ticket not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm implementing the OAuth 2 refresh token with ASP.NET API2 and OWIN, the following code is my OAuthAuthorizationOptions

```
 public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions AuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_AuthorizationServerOptions == null)
            {
                _AuthorizationServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
                {
                    AuthenticationType = OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(AuthSettings.TokenEndpoint),
                    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString(AuthSettings.AuthorizeEndpoint),
                    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(AuthSettings.TokenExpiry),
                    Provider = new CustomOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider(AuthSettings.PublicClientId),
                    // TODO: Remove the dependency with Thinktecture.IdentityModel library here
                    AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJWTFormat(),
                    RefreshTokenProvider = new CustomRefreshTokenProvider()
                };
            }
            return _AuthorizationServerOptions;
        }
    }
```

Here is my CustomRefreshTokenProvider class

```
public override Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var identifier = context.Ticket.Identity.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (identifier == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(identifier.Value))
        {
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
        var refreshToken = HashHelper.Hash(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));
        var tokenIssued = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var tokenExpire = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(AuthSettings.RefreshTokenExpiry);
        context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = tokenIssued;
        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = tokenExpire;
        context.Ticket.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
        var protectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();
        AuthService.AddUserRefreshTokenSession(
            identifier.Value,
            refreshToken,
            tokenIssued,
            tokenExpire,
            protectedTicket);
        context.SetToken(refreshToken);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
    public override Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        var refToken = context.Token;
        var protectedTicket = AuthService.GetProtectedTicket(refToken);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(protectedTicket))
        {
            context.DeserializeTicket(protectedTicket);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

I have used postman to send POST request to the token endpoint as below
[Postman refresh token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hddsx.png)
the server return 400 bad request status code.
I debugged and found that the context.DeserializeTicket(protectedTicket) 
throw an Exception

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' in System.Web.dll
```

I don't think it is the expiration issue because 
the AuthSettings.RefreshTokenExpiry is 30 days from now.
I also tried to add Machine key to my web.config [OAuth Refresh Token does not deserialize / invalid_grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066840/oauth-refresh-token-does-not-deserialize-invalid-grant)

but it still not working.

Does anyone have an idea?
Any solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you found any solution, i have the exact same problem.

Comment: @Amin K Sorry for the late response, I just answered, is it is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answered.
I have resolved this issue and end up with a solution that remove entirely Thinktecture.Identity out of my project, since it's somehow conflict with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT.dll

Another solution if you still want to use Thinktecture.Identity is that downgrade System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT to v4.0.2.206221351 (this version worked for me, I haven't tested with another version).

Here is the code of CustomJWTFormat.cs

```
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
    using MST.Service.Core.Logging;
    using System;
    using System.Security.Claims;

    namespace MST.Service.Core.Auth
    {
        public class CustomJWTFormat : ISecureDataFormat
        {
            private byte[] _SymetricKey = null;
            public CustomJWTFormat()
            {
                _SymetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(AuthSettings.JwtTokenSecret);
            }
            /// 
            /// Create jwt token 
            /// 
            /// 
            /// Token string
            public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
            {
                var tokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken(
                    AuthSettings.Issuer,
                    AuthSettings.JwtAudiences,
                    data.Identity.Claims,
                    DateTime.UtcNow,
                    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(AuthSettings.TokenExpiry),
                     new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(
                        new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(_SymetricKey),
                    System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature,
                    System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest)
                    );
                var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);
                return token;
            }

            public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
            {
                var tokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var validationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    AuthenticationType = OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                    ValidIssuers = new string[] { AuthSettings.Issuer },
                    ValidAudiences = new string[] { AuthSettings.JwtAudiences },
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(_SymetricKey)

                };
                System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken securityToken = null;

                ClaimsPrincipal principal = null;
                try
                {
                    principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(protectedText, validationParameters, out securityToken);
                    var validJwt = securityToken as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken;

                    if (validJwt == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid JWT");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LoggerManager.AuthLog.Error($"Parse token error: {ex.ToString()}");
                    return null;
                }

                // Validation passed. Return a valid AuthenticationTicket:
                return new AuthenticationTicket(principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties());
            }
        }
    }
```

and JWTBearerAuthenticationOptions (if you host Resource Server and Authorization Server in the same machine)

```
 public static JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions JwtAuthenticationOptions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_JwtAuthenticationOptions == null)
            {
                _JwtAuthenticationOptions = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    //AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                    AuthenticationType = OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { AuthSettings.JwtAudiences },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(AuthSettings.Issuer, AuthSettings.JwtTokenSecret)
                    }
                };
            }
            return _JwtAuthenticationOptions;
        }
    }
```

in Startup.cs just register middleware as usual

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(AuthenticationOptions.JwtAuthenticationOptions);
```